# Urysohn's Lemma and Normal space

Tags: general-topology

Assume that $X$ is $T_1$-topological space such that, for all pairs of closed sets $A,B\subset X$ with $A\cap B$, there exist a continuous function $f:X\rightarrow [0,1]$ with $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in A$ and $f(z)=1$ for all $z\in B$. prove that $X$ is normal.

I have idea to prove this question but i do not know it is correct or no? and how I have to continue to get proof?

My idea: let $ g:A\rightarrow [0,1]$ be constant function $g(x)=0$  , $\forall x\in A$ and similarly $h:B\rightarrow [0,1]$ be constant function  $h(z)=1$ for all $z\in B$.
As $A\cap B= \varnothing$ we can define $f(y)=g(y)$ for $y\in A$ or $f(y)=h(y)$ for $y\in B$ is continuous map.
Since $A, B$ is closed and $g, h$ continuous, there exist extension $F:X\rightarrow [0,1]$ that continuous.
I will be thankful for every idea or different approach.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need your $g$ and $h$. Let $A$ and $B$ be disjoint closed sets in $X$. Your hypothesis says that there is a continuous $f:X\to[0,1]$ such that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in A$ and $f(x)=1$ for all $x\in B$. Now consider the open sets

$$U=f^{-1}\left[\left[0,\frac12\right)\right]=\left\{x\in X:f(x)<\frac12\right\}$$

and

$$V=f^{-1}\left[\left(\frac12,1\right]\right]=\left\{x\in X:f(x)>\frac12\right\}\;.$$

Comment: Thank you so much, so we have two open set without intersection, I mean $A\subset U$ (A is closed and subset of U) and B is open subset of V similarly, and based on definition X is normal? i just want to be sure.

Comment: @Zeezee: That’s right: $U$ is an open nbhd of $A$, $V$ is an open nbhd of $B$ and $U\cap V=\varnothing$. Since we can do this for **every** pair of disjoint closed sets in $X$, $X$ is by definition normal.